# Trying to count number of elements but it returns zero

Tags: count, cypress, element, variable-length

***The elements***:

```html
<div>class="product-image-container"</div> 
<br>
<br>
```

***The code:***

```js
countMaterials(){  
  let countItems = 0;
  cy.get('#center_column').find("div").then((items) => {
    countItems = items.length;
  });
  return countItems;
}
```

I'm trying to make it dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use aliases as well to get the count and then access it later something like:

```js
cy.get('#center_column').find('div').its('length').as('itemLength')

cy.get('@itemLength').then((itemLength) => {
  cy.log(itemLength) //prints itemLength
  // Access itemLength here
})
```